# find server's "announcements" channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm not entirely sure if this makes any sense, but since it's viewable in the app, shouldn't there be an endpoint for the announcement channel setting?

This isn't a piece of code that isn't working, it's a lacking feature.

Also, it's apparently called "new member message channel"...

[image]

Comment: Please add more description about what you expected to happen, what you tried, and what you think its at fault - ideally what piece of code.

Comment: Announcement channel? There is no "in-built" announcement channel.

Comment: @Wright added picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access or update the new member message channel, you must be on rewrite branch of discord.py.

On the rewrite branch, guilds have a property [`guild.system_channel`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.system_channel) which is where system messages are sent to, though currently only member join notifications are sent there.

```
# Getting the channel
ch = guild.system_channel
# Setting the channel
await guild.edit(system_channel=ch)
```

However, this feature is not on async branch of discord.py because the library author dropped support for that version many months ago.